# How to avoid NPM EACCES: permission denied?

Tags: angular, macos, npm

I'm getting a ton of

> EACCES: permission denied

and

> checkPermissions

errors when running `npm i -g npm`.

It is suggesting:

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

I am the admin so what does it want?

Comment: You can try running your powershell / cmd as administrator, or making sure your user has permissions on the relevant directories

Comment: As mentioned, user is admin. Powershell? What is wrong with terminal.

Comment: Are you using windows, or linux? If you're using windows as I suspect, right click on the icon for the command prompt, and click "Run as administrator"

Comment: Read the tags...

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this very often. Often this is the case when node_modules folder to be updated by npm is being accessed from some process. Try closing any opened folder in File Explorer, closing any running ng serve session and other opened terminal. **Also close any opened UI of your application in web-browser.**
Don't know what exactly causes this issue, but it's always solved by one or the other of the above methods.

Comment: Nothing. Even rebooted the computer.

Comment: My guess is it's because of one of the process which is using files which require modification when hitting npm. sudo is one of the ways it can be solved, but for cases where you can't use sudo commands, hit and trial of closing the culprit process is the only way I solve it. BTW are you sure there wasn't any process using node_modules folder after reboot? Maybe you started something or OS restored some process using that folder?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to proceed any command with `sudo`.